# JavaEE Webapp Custom authorization from outside a Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, authorization

I'm having a JavaEE Website running on a cloud-platform.
Now I want to use two types of authentications:

1. Is from an SSO-System, which is well integrated in the platfrom and works very nicely.
2. Is the problematic part: I want to authorize a user from 1) for the time of a session, and give him access to a more restricted resource.

***Some details***

- I get the user and his data from 1).
- The user first has to ask for permission to 2), which can be denyed or granted. A user gets authorization from a service, which is outside of the scope of his servlet.
- For this purpose I pass a User-POJO (with the session of this user as a member) to a service.
- If the service grants the rights to this user, it will set an attribute to the user session:

  ```
             userSession.setAttribute("auth", "granted");
  ```

To restrict access to that resource I use a Filter:

```
   @WebFilter("/supersecret/*")
   public class NiceFilter implements Filter {


   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();

    // check
    if (session.getAttribute("auth") != "granted")
        // redirect to login
    else
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

  }
      //...
```

While this is currently working, I feel that my solution is very sloppy.

1. Altering the user-session outside the scope of a servlet seems to be bad practice.
2. Adding an attribute to the session for security-purposes is probably not a good idea?

I'd rather want to use standard JavaEE-mechanisms, but most of them are already used for auth-method 1), like declaring *login-config* in the web.xml.

Any ideas for a more robust solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you find a better way yet? I use Spring Security, which allows you to create roles for a user. You can check the session, set a role and this role will define the level of access.

Comment: I had to stick with that method. Saw some examples using a similar approach, so I felt I could just use it.